# IntelliJ IDEA not picking up correct application-{}.properties file

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have a spring boot 1.5.1 project that uses profile properties file.  In my /src/main/resources I have all my properties files
[image]

When using IntelliJ 2016.3.4 I set the

> Run Configuration | Active Profile

to "local" and run it.  I see this in the console:

> The following profiles are active: local

But there is a value in the property file 
 `data.count.users=2`

and used as:

```
@Value("${data.count.users}")
private int userCount;
```

that is not being picked up and thus causing the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   placeholder 'data.count.users' in string value "${data.count.users}"

However, if I run this via gradle

```
bootRun {
  systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', System.properties['spring.profiles.active'] }
```

as

> gradle bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=local

then everything starts up using the local profile as expected.  Can anyone see why this is not being properly picked up?  In IntelliJ Project Structure I have my /src/main/resources defined as my Resource Folders.

UPDATE:

Adding screenshot of Configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pease add Spring facet to your Spring Boot module to get full support
2. Is classpath of module `heimdall` the correct one, i.e. does it contain the shown `resources` folder with your `application.properties`?
3. If this doesn't help, please file a minimum sample project reproducing the exact structure of your project in our bugtracker, there are too many variables to investigate https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: This was it, setting the Spring facet was the missing piece.  I guess its stored differently between 15 & 16 ?

Comment: How do you do step 1?

Answer (score 11):

I could be wrong here but it doesn't look like the `spring.profiles.active` environment variable is actually set in your configuration, regardless of what you've selected as your Active Profile. This may be a bug with IntelliJ.

However, setting the environment variable in Run -> Edit Configurations definitely works for me.

[image]

Comment: thanks I tried in the File->Settings dialog but that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Using -Dspring.config.location in VM options in IntelliJ helped me.

```
-Dspring.config.location=file:/C:/Users/<project path>/src/main/resources/application-dev.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be due to a non-standard configuration setup, for instance:

```
src/main/resources
├── application.properties
├── config1
│   ├── application-dev.properties
│   ├── application-prod.properties
│   ├── application.properties
│   └── logback-spring.xml
├── config2
│   ├── application-dev.properties
│   ├── application-prod.properties
│   ├── application.properties
│   └── logback-spring.xml
└── config3
    ├── application-dev.properties
    ├── application-prod.properties
    ├── application.properties
    └── logback-spring.xml
```

This can be solved by passing using the parameters `logging.config` & `spring.config.name` for logback & spring respectively. For the above example:

```
java -jar \
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev \
-Dlogging.config=classpath:config1/logback-spring.xml \
-Dspring.config.name=application,config1/application \
target/my-application.0.0.1.jar
```

Here root `application.properties` is used, overridden by `config1/application.properties`, overridden by `config1/application-dev.properties`. The parameters (environment variables) can be specified in IDEA's run configuration in `VM Options`.

As far as advanced IDE support (highlighting, completion etc.) is concerned, there is an open issue for complex/custom configuration setups: [IDEA-180498](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180498)