# How to point to application-local.yml instead of application-dev.yml in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, yaml, intellij-plugin

How to point to local application.yml instead of other .yml files. IntelliJ is taking application.yml by default. I want to change configuration to point to local yml, so that I can run  application in my local.

Comment: Elaborate on your question, please. What is the project type? How it is configured and how do you check what .yaml file is in use? How do you run the application?

Comment: If it is Spring application and you run it via IntelliJ IDEA, you may set the active profile using environment variables. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42461757/8203759

Answer (score 3):

Go to the run configuration and add to CLI arguments:

```
--spring.config.additional-location=classpath:application-local.yml --spring.profiles.active=local
```